# Get all paths to files in the Content folder in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I need to list all relative paths to files in my Content folder.

I wrote something that works, but it seems a bit brittle. Is there a better/smarter way to do this?

```
var contentPaths = GetRelativePathsToRoot("~/Content/").ToList();

private IEnumerable<string> GetRelativePathsToRoot(string virtualPath)
    {
        var physicalPath = Server.MapPath(virtualPath);
        var absolutePaths = Directory.GetFiles(physicalPath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);                       

        var relativePaths = new List<string>();
        foreach (var absolutePath in absolutePaths)
        {                
            var splittedPath = virtualPath.Split(new string[] { "/" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);               
            var virtualFolderName = splittedPath[splittedPath.Length -1];
            var relativePath = absolutePath
                .Substring(absolutePath.IndexOf(virtualFolderName))
                .Replace("\\", "/");                

            relativePaths.Add(Url.Content("~/" + relativePath));
        }

        return relativePaths;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following seems shorter:

```
private IEnumerable<string> GetRelativePathsToRoot(string virtualPath)
{
    var physicalPath = Server.MapPath(virtualPath);
    var absolutePaths = Directory.EnumerateFiles(
        physicalPath, 
        "*.*", 
        SearchOption.AllDirectories
    );
    return absolutePaths.Select(
        x => Url.Content(virtualPath + x.Replace(physicalPath, ""))
    );
}
```

Also notice that I am using [`Directory.EnumerateFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383571.aspx) instead of `Directory.GetFiles`. This method was introduced in .NET 4.0 and returns an `IEnumreable<string>` instead of a `string[]`. The benefits of this are more than obvious. Internally this method uses the [FindFirstFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [FindNextFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364428%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Win32 functions. This means that the actual file system search is performed only when you start enumerating over the resultset.